# CDT indexer error with typedef inside of ifdef

Tags: c++, typedef, eclipse-cdt, conditional-compilation, indexer

I've problems with the indexer. It critizes the use of SOCKET in the method:

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_

#ifdef linux
typedef int SOCKET;
#endif

class Test {
public:
    void test(const SOCKET src);
};

#endif /* TEST_H_ */
```

my eclipse version is: Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) Build id: 20150219-0600

my CDT is 8.6.0.201502131403

here's the message from indexer: Type 'SOCKET' could not be resolved

Some facts:

- 'linux' is defined!
- if I remove the 'ifdef' around the typedef the indexer reports no error any more!

Nevertheless the code will be compiled with and without ifdef. But I want to solve the indexing problem with the ifdef. Any idea's?

Regards
Rainer

Comment: To be able to diagnose the problem with why the indexer is not seeing linux correctly in the first place. Can you confirm OS and GCC version. In particular are you using "gcc" or something like "arm-linux-gcc"?

Comment: In the meantime of sorting out an answer for your specific case, you could have a look at the manual  on scanner discovery http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_pref_build_scanner_discovery.htm

Comment: my OS is OpenSuse 13.1 64-bit  GCC is c++ (SUSE Linux) 4.8.1 20130909 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 202388]  The compiler is the defined via an environment variable CXX set automatically from Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Is the ifdef greyed out like in this screenshot:

[image: Screen Shot of Greyed out editor contents]

If so, then CDT does not know the "linux" symbol is defined. To get it defined you have a few choices, depending on your setup.

### Managed Make

Managed make means you are letting CDT create your makefiles for you.

Option 1: you are native linux using GCC then I suspect something is going wrong, please file a bug.

Option 2: you are doing cross-compiling, then it is a setup issue on your project/workspace (unfortunately more detail needed here).

### Standard Make

Standard make means you are writing the makefiles yourself (or some other tool is).

Option 1: You have not run a build from within Eclipse CDT, so CDT does not know what your build settings are. CDT analyses the output of running make to determine what settings should be.

Option 2: You ran make from within CDT, but you had command echoing suppressed (@ on commands). Try running the make without that.

Option 3: You need to tell CDT about symbols that are defined. To tell CDT:

1. Open Project Properties (right-click on project and choose "Properties")
2. Open "C/C++ General" - "Paths and Symbols" setting page and choose "Symbols" tab
3. Click the Add button to define a new symbol
4. Fill in the details of the symbol. In your case you probably want Name=linux and Value=1 (I used unknown_symbol in the screenshots because linux was already defined on my system). You probably want to apply this to all languages and all build configurations by checking the two checkboxes.

[image: symbols]

5. Press OK repeatedly until you get back to the editor. One of the dialogs you may get will prompt you to rebuild the index. Say yes to that.

[image: rebuild index prompt]

Comment: Thanks to Jonah. I use Standard Make and Option 3 solved my problem.

Comment: Excellent. It would be great if you could accept my answer in that case.

Comment: I had an addionally question. I run the build within Eclipse and I think 'linux' is defined because the build itself works. Only the indexer reports a problem. So isn't there a problem in the indexer? As I understand the indexer doesn't find the defined 'linux'! How can I check the defines for Indexer and/or compiler?

Comment: Kindly ask that in a new question and I will be pleased to answer it there. My desire is to build up good quality questions and answers about eclipse CDT, but to make that happen we need each of these good questions by you to end up as questions in SO instead of hidden in the comments.

Comment: On second thought, I think you are asking that question. I will amend my answer.